# What does the term $dN_t/N_t$ mean in a Stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The following is an excerpt from page 62, chapter 5 in Oksendal's textbook on Stochastic Differential Equations:
$$dN_t = r N_t dt + \alpha N_t dB_t$$
or,
$$ \dfrac{dN_t}{N_t} = r dt + \alpha dB_t$$
Hence,$$ \int_0^t \dfrac{dN_s}{N_s} = rt + \alpha B_t$$

What does the term $dN_t/N_t$ mean in the second line? The textbook says
$$ dX_t = u dt + v dB_t$$
is shorthand for $$X_t(\omega) = X_0 (\omega) + \int_0^t u(s, \omega) ds + \int_0^t v (s, \omega) dB_s$$
but it does not attribute any particular value to $dN_t(\omega)$. Just from this I cannot see any way to give a proper meaning to equations like
$ \dfrac{dX_t}{X_t} = u dt + v dB$, or see how dividing by $N_t$ in the first equation is justified. The textbook does not elaborate on this further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\int_0^t \frac{dN_s}{N_s} = \int_0^t \frac{\mu_s}{N_s} ds + \int_0^t \frac{\sigma_s}{N_s} dB_s$ if $dN_t=\mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$.

Answer (score 1):

SDEs of that type have solutions that stay away from zero, hence, the division by $N_t$ is justified. By Ito's formula the explicit solution of the SDE is
$$
N_t=N_0\exp(\alpha B_t-\alpha^2t/2-rt)
$$
which is never zero (let's exclute the trivial case $N_0=0\Rightarrow N_t\equiv 0).$